# How to detect Arabic chars using perl regex?

Tags: regex, perl, utf-8, arabic

I'm parsing some html pages, and need to detect any Arabic char inside..
Tried various regexs, but no luck..

Does anyone know working way to do that?

Thanks

---

Here is the page I'm processing:  http://pastie.org/2509936

And my code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use LWP::UserAgent; 
@MyAgent::ISA = qw(LWP::UserAgent); 

# set inheritance 
$ua = LWP::UserAgent->new; 
$q = 'pastie.org/2509936';; 
$request = HTTP::Request->new('GET', $q); 
$response = $ua->request($request); 
if ($response->is_success) { 
    if ($response->content=~/[\p{Script=Arabic}]/g) { 
        print "found arabic"; 
    } else { 
        print "not found"; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Show the sample string that you pretend to fail.

Comment: This is the sample string: احتفل الفنان المصري الشاب خالد سليم بخطبته على فتاة من خارج الوسط الفني بشكل سري وبعيدًا عن وسائل الإ

Comment: You have to use `decoded_content`, not `content`. Otherwise you just have encoded bytes, which are useless.  And you should use the pattern `/\p{Arabic}/`, without the `/g` and without the extra brackets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT (as I have obviously wandered into tchrist's area of expertise). Skip using `$response->content`, which always returns a raw byte string, and use `$response->decoded_content`, which applies any decoding hints it gets from the response headers.

---

The page you are downloading is UTF-8 encoded, but you are not reading it as UTF-8 (in fairness, there are no hints on the page about what the encoding is
 [update: the server does return the header `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8`, though]).

You can see if this if you examine `$response->content`:

```
use List::Util 'max';
my $max_ord = max map{ord}split //, $response->content;
print "max ord of response content is $max_ord\n";
```

If you get a value less than 256, then you are reading this content in as raw bytes, and your strings will never match `/\p{Arabic}/`. You must decode the input as UTF-8 before you apply the regex:

```
use Encode;
my $content = decode('utf-8', $response->content);
# now check  $content =~ /\p{Arabic}/
```

Sometimes (and now I am wading well outside my area of expertise) the page you are loading contains hints about how it is decoded, and `$response->content` may already be decoded correctly. In that case, the `decode` call above is unnecessary and may be harmful. See [other SO posts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bperl%5D%20guess%20encoding) on detecting the encoding of an arbitrary string.

Comment: Ewww! Don’t ever guess the content type like that!  That is what `decoded_content` is for.

Answer (score 6):

If you're using Perl, you should be able to use the Unicode script matching operator. `/\p{Arabic}/`

If that doesn't work, you'll have to look up the range of Unicode characters for Arabic, and test them something like this `/[\x{0600}\x{0601}...\x{06FF}]/`.

Comment: \p{Arabic} doesn't work, while second solution returns true even for HTML pages with western characters only? Strange

Comment: Try \p{Script=Arabic}. That second part is surprising though.

Comment: Disbelieve. You are not telling us something.

Comment: Make sure the input is decoded correctly -- if the input is encoded in UTF-8, make sure you are reading it as UTF-8.

Comment: Here is the page I'm processing:
http://pastie.org/2509936

And my code is:
    #!usr/bin/perl
    use LWP::UserAgent;
    @MyAgent::ISA = qw(LWP::UserAgent); # set inheritance
    $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
    $q = 'http://pastie.org/2509936';
    $request = HTTP::Request->new('GET', $q);
    $response = $ua->request($request);
    if ($response->is_success)
    {
        if ($response->content=~/[\p{Script=Arabic}]/g)
        {
            print "found arabic";
        }
        else
        {
            print "not found";
        }
    }

Comment: Sorry, don't know how to reformat text, tried with 4 spaces indent :(

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, at least in .NET regexps, you need to use `\p{IsArabic}`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, This is not an answer, it is more of a comment. I know that your rep does not let you comment, but you should still not use the answers as comments.

Comment: Thanks, Inbar. I'll take it into account.