# Perl pattern matching for a specific line

Tags: perl, pattern-matching

I'm new to Perl and Regex. I need to read a line in an Arabic text file with IBM864 encoding  by using a regular expression specific to that line in file. The line structure is as follows:

16 whitespace character, 4 arabic characters, 36 whitespace characters, 3 digits, 2 whitespaces, \n escape character.

please advise.
Thank you.

Comment: Maybe this link is useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7365320/how-to-detect-arabic-chars-using-perl-regex

Comment: It is usual to pick out specific identifying features of a line rather than matching the pattern of the *entire* line. Is there some text or a number in there that tells you that this is the line you want?

Comment: this is a spool file and this specific line's data is different from page to page yet the structure of the data is fixed as I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Well on the face of it what you want is a regex like this

```
/ ^ \s{16} \p{Arabic}{4} \s{36} \d{3} \s{2} $ /x
```